# Problems with Ajax when adding items to my shopping Cart PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I just started to learn how to program and I have been having issues with ajax when it comes to adding items to my cart. Everything is fine when it comes to adding items, its the ajax that is not working and my page constantly keeps refreshing. For the code since there is a lot of it I will put the things I think are the most important.

Index.php

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){


        $(document).on('click', '.add_to_cart', function(){
    var product_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var product_name = $('#name'+product_id+'').val();
    var product_price = $('#price'+product_id+'').val();
    var product_quantity = $('#quantity'+product_id).val();
    if(product_quantity > 0)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"index.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{product_id:product_id, product_name:product_name, product_price:product_price, product_quantity:product_quantity},
            success:function(data)
            {
                alert("Item has been Added into Cart");
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert("lease Enter Number of Quantity");
    }
});

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<?php
include_once'widget/header.php';
    if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
    include_once"include/addcart.php";
    include_once "widget/shoppingcart.php";
}
?>
</header>
<main>
<div class="item-container">
    <?php
        $item = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM itemlist ORDER BY title");  
        include_once 'widget/container.php';
    ?>
</div>
</main>
```

Addcart.php

```
<?php

    $row_ids = array();
    //session_destroy();

    //check if Add to Cart button has been submitted
    if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'add_to_cart')){
        if(isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])){

            //keep track of how mnay products are in the shopping cart
            $count = count($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);

            //create sequantial array for matching array keys to products id's
            $row_ids = array_column($_SESSION['shopping_cart'], 'id');

            if (!in_array(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id'), $row_ids)){
            $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$count] = array
                (
                    'id' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id'),
                    'name' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name'),
                    'price' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'price'),
                    'quantity' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'quantity')
                );
                // header("Location:index.php?addedtocart");
            }
            else { //product already exists, increase quantity
                //match array key to id of the product being added to the cart
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($row_ids); $i++){
                    if ($row_ids[$i] == filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id')){
                        //add item quantity to the existing product in the array
                        $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$i]['quantity'] += filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'quantity');
                        // header("Location:index.php?multtocart");
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        else { //if shopping cart doesn't exist, create first product with array key 0
            //create array using submitted form data, start from key 0 and fill it with values
            $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][0] = array
            (
                'id' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id'),
                'name' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name'),
                'price' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'price'),
                'quantity' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'quantity')
            );
        }
    }
    if (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'delete')) {
        //loop thru intil products in shop cart == variable
        foreach ($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $row) {
            if ($row['id'] == filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id')) {
                unset($_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$key]);
            }
        }
        $_SESSION['shopping_cart'] =array_values($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);
    }

    ?>
```

Shoppingcart.php

```
<div class="cart-container" align="right">
            <div class="table-responsive">  
            <table class="table">  
            <table class="table">  
                <tr><th colspan="5"><h5>Order Details</h5></th></tr>   
            <tr>  
                 <th width="40%">Product Name</th>  
                 <th width="10%">Quantity</th>  
                 <th width="20%">Price</th>  
                 <th width="15%">Total</th>  
                 <th width="5%">Action</th>  
            </tr>  
            <?php   
            if(!empty($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])):  

                 $total = 0;  

                 foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $product): 
            ?>  
            <tr>  
               <td><?php echo $product['name']; ?></td>  
               <td><?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></td>  
               <td>$ <?php echo $product['price']; ?></td>  
               <td>$ <?php echo number_format($product['quantity'] * $product['price'], 2); ?></td>  
               <td>
                   <form method="post">
                       <input class="delete" type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
                       <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $product['id']; ?>">
                   </form>
               </td>  
            </tr>  
            <?php  
                      $total = $total + ($product['quantity'] * $product['price']);  
                 endforeach;  
            ?>  
            <tr>  
                 <td colspan="3" align="right">Total</td>  
                 <td align="right">$ <?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?></td>

                 <td></td>  
            </tr>  
            <tr>
                <!-- Show checkout button only if the shopping cart is not empty -->
                <td colspan="5">
                 <?php 
                    if (isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])):
                    if (count($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) > 0):
                 ?>
                    <a href="checkout.php" class="button">Checkout</a>
                 <?php endif; endif; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php  
            endif;
            ?>  
            </table>   
    </div>
    </div>
```

Container.php

```
<?php
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($item)) {
        ?>
                    <div class='item-box'>
                    <img class='item_img' src="itemimg/<?php echo $row['img']; ?>"><figcaption><?php echo $row['title']; ?></ficgcaption>
                    <form method="post" class="add-form">
                    <div class='input-group xs-2'>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="quantity<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" name="quantity" value="1">
                        <input class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm add-btns add_to_cart" type="submit" id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" name="add_to_cart" value="Add To Cart">
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="name<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['title'] ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" id="price<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" name="price" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                    </div>

                    </form>
        <?php
                }

        ?>
```

Comment: you can add item, but the ajax is not working? But your ajax is the one who add items to your cart

Answer (score 0):

Your page will refresh because you are not telling your form to not submit by the default method (which is to reload the page as a `POST`). To stop the page from reloading and let ajax do the submission, you need to inject the event and then use `preventDefault()`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_to_cart', function(e){
    // This will stop the form from submitting and allow the rest of the 
    // ajax to continue working. If you don't have this, you will immediately
    // submit the form which negates the use of ajax
    e.preventDefault();
```